# How to check all post request from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check my application's all post request. I have created a new route option.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'any';
```

this will call any controller.  This is my any.php

```
if ( !defined('BASEPATH') ) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Any extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }


    function index(){
        if(  $_POST ){
            if( validate() ){
                // redirect to error controller
            }else{
                //redirect to current page url
            }
        }else{
            //redirect to current page url
        }
    }
}
```

But when i redirect via this function rediect($this->uri->uri_string), I got some error page. regarding cannot redirect to its self.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong it will stuck in a redirect loop... after first time it will always invoke the else condition where you have put the redirect... You can either load a view in else condition or redirect to other function where you load a view.

**UPDATE**

Here is your work aorund for what you are trying to achieve:
Create a post_controller_construct hook with following code

```
class validate_post_request
{
    function validate_request()
    {
        //Here i am supposing your validate function is in helper 
        //which is included in autoload. The function returns
        //true if validation passed and false on failure
        if( !validate() ) {
            show_error('Your error message to display');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot load the view. I want to check all the page request. Can't do it for every individual pages. Is there any way to change the url with additional parameter, then check it with...

Comment: yes you can redirect to another method from here by passing the parameter in your function

Comment: you can also achieve your target by using hooks... check this out [codeigniter hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: hmm.. can u give me example for all post request handle